# Parsing Outlook emails with embedded images, add to Sharepoint list item as attachment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook, outlook-2010

Yes, very similar question to: [Python: parsing emails with embedded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332400/python-parsing-emails-with-embedded-images)

,but I'd like to make this a more specific question pertaining to Outlook emails.

I receive an Outlook email with an embedded image, and the image is embedded as:

`img width="277" height="588" id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01CD708B.77509FF0" alt="Description: cid:image001.png@01CD7089.09DE0C70">`

I don't see the base64 encoding, just `src="cid:image001.png@01CD708B.77509FF0"`, how do I parse that and add it as an attachment to a Sharepoint list item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook embedded image to HTML with inline image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090608/outlook-embedded-image-to-html-with-inline-image)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your answer might be here: [Outlook embedded image to HTML with inline image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090608/outlook-embedded-image-to-html-with-inline-image)

He recommends EasyMail from Quiksoft.

http://www.quiksoft.com/emdotnet/

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440356/extracting-embedded-images-from-outlook-email and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259308/net-how-to-extract-embedded-image-from-email-message

Comment: Thanks, having some issues referencing EWS though.

Comment: I've completed this start to finish. Updates soon (when I have time ;)).

Comment: Quiksoft has shutdown.

Comment: Not surprising since this answer is from half a decade ago ;)